# If there is a real path under the public folder, same as the route path

Tags: laravel, directory, routes, laravel-8

I have some folders under public folder. For example

```
public/games/game1
public/games/game2
```

and this folder includes  `css`, `js`, `sprites` etc.

And I have routes (in `web.php`)

```
Route::prefix('games')->group(function (){
 Route::get('game1',[GameController::class, 'game1Index'])->name('game1');
 Route::get('game2',[GameController::class, 'game2Index'])->name('game2');
});
```

Whenever I call these routes, it searches index.php under "public/games/game..n" folder without ever visiting gamecontroller. And it gives an error saying "page not found".

If i change the name of my route (games -> game-list). For example

```
Route::prefix('game-list')->group(function (){
     Route::get('game1',[GameController::class, 'game1Index'])->name('game1');
     Route::get('game2',[GameController::class, 'game2Index'])->name('game2');
    });
```

It goes to the `GameController.php` and works correctly. but this time the external, relative links I gave for javascript and css files explode.

To solve this, I apply a solution to the links one by one (inside javascript path, and css path, adding to ../games/game1). This time it works completely, however, it bothers me that it is this way.  for example:

```
s_oSpriteLibrary.addSprite("mask_slot","../games/game1/sprites/mask_slot.png");
```

Is there any other decent solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your routes should not point to folders that already exist in your public path.

You cannot have a public path with the same name as your route because Laravel will not know whether `"/games"` is for the controller, or for the styles or js etc.

That is why the very first instance of your `web.php` was not working and the second one did. The `games` folder already exists in your public path.

Instead of doing that, you should put your `css` `js` `sprites` folders and files in an `assets` folder instead.